# SharePoint onprem Rest API calls From Java Application

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Getting Unauthorized exception, while trying to access SharePoint Rest APIs for POST Requests from java web application.As per MSDN, Formdigest is mandatory for Post requests.How do we consume SharePoint Rest APIs from non-Microsoft applications?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this post [Post to SharePoint 2013 from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286413/post-to-sharepoint-2013-from-java). For your credentials, I have personally used NTLM (Windows) authentication like so:

```
Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
        .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new JCIFSNTLMSchemeFactory())
        .register(AuthSchemes.BASIC, new BasicSchemeFactory())
        .register(AuthSchemes.DIGEST, new DigestSchemeFactory())
        .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory())
        .register(AuthSchemes.KERBEROS, new KerberosSchemeFactory())
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
        .build(); 
NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials(user, password, workstation, domain);
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this project I've made to wrap common operations over the sharepoint rest api

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java